Independent statements in model definition and then DAG
In this paper in Section 3.1, they give a Baysian linear regression model and then a DAG, which I show below.


From my understanding a DAG tells us how the joint distribution can be factorised.
But in order to have such a DAG, do we not need extra independent statements such as:
$$y_{ij} \perp \xi^2 \; \mid x_{ij} , \beta_j, \sigma_j^2$$
